# ObjectDisposedException when reading requests HttpContent in test

Tags: c#, mocking, tdd

I'm integrating a 3rd part API using TDD, and so I am implementing a HttpClient wrapper interface that exposes the possible api calls and so on.

I want to test that the correct payload was sent in a post method, but when I try to read the string content from my injected fake `HttpMessageHandler` I get an `ObjectDisposedException`. Is there a better way to test this?

Test code:

```
[Fact]
public async void PostSignupRequest_RequestSent_PostedSerializedRequestAsContent()
{
    var client = MakeOnboardingClient();
    _fakeJsonSerializer.SerializedResult = "some json";

    await client.PostSignupRequest(_someSignupRequest);

    Assert.Equal("some json", await _fakeMessageHandler.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
}
```

My HttpMessageHandler spy/test double:

```
public class FakeHttpMessageHandler : HttpMessageHandler
{
    public HttpRequestMessage Request;
    public string ResponseContent = string.Empty;

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Request = request;
        return await Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            Content = new StringContent(ResponseContent)
        });
    }
}
```

Production code:

```
public async Task<SignupRequestResponse> PostSignupRequest(SignupRequest request)
{
    var json = _jsonSerializer.Serialize(request);
    await _httpClient.PostAsync(/* url */, new StringContent(json));
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of _httpClient in your production code?

Comment: It is an instance of `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`, constructed by injecting a fake `HttpMessageHandler` to intercept and record all requests made (and prevent them from actually being sent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a fix now. In my HttpMessageHandler fake I don't just save the Request now, I also explicitly save the content string (which can be extracted at that point since the HttpClient hasn't disposed the request yet). My fake now looks like this:

```
public class FakeHttpMessageHandler : HttpMessageHandler
{
    public HttpRequestMessage Request;
    public string LastRequestString = string.Empty;
    public string ResponseContent = string.Empty;

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.Content != null) // needed this to prevent some NPEs in other tests, YMMV
        {
            LastRequestString = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        Request = request;
        return await Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            Content = new StringContent(ResponseContent)
        });
    }
}
```